# Python: Kill processes started by multiprocessing.Pool in a cgi script when user stops page load

Tags: python, google-chrome, cgi

I have a cgi script that starts many processes via Pool from the multiprocessing module. How can I make sure all these processes are killed if the user decides to quit loading the webpage? By "quit", I mean either pressing the stop load button on a browser, closing the tab, or quitting the browser.

I know the terminate() function from multiprocessing can stop processes, but how can the script register that the user has ended the page load, and consequently run this command?

Unfortunately, these processes call another cgi script on another server, which requests data from a database. I can imagine it might be difficult to stop those requests, but is it possible to at least stop the orignal python processes started from Pool on my own machine?